# Determine when client disconnects from a gRPC UnaryStream

Tags: grpc-python

When a client disconnects from the server I need to be able to catch that signal to perform some housekeeping. I can't seem to find anything within the docs (https://grpclib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html). Is there a callback I need to register to? When I attempt to write on the `stream` it doesn't raise an exception so I'm assuming the server removes the function (that represents the client's connection) entirely from the pool.

My server is written in Python 3.9. grpclib 0.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grpclib` is one community implementation of gRPC protocol: https://github.com/vmagamedov/grpclib

`grpcio` is the official gRPC Python implementation: https://github.com/grpc/grpc

Protocol-wise, there are two types of client disconnects. First, the client half-closes the connection, no more traffic will be allowed from client to server, the other way is okay; second, the TCP connection ended, this depends on the transport library to report the error

Comment: Oh awesome! I’ll check that out/mark as resolved when I can find the next opportunity.